# Can a JavaFX 2 applet request focus and so focus on browser / tab?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, focus, javafx-2

I'm wondering if there would be any solution to show and focus on browser's tab containing a javafx 2 applet programmatically from the applet.
I don't think there's a simple solution, but who knows :)

PS : Obviously, stage.requestFocus() and stage.toFront() don't work.

Comment: If there is a way to do it in JS, write a `function` & call it from the applet.  If not, then no.  BTW - why do you want to cram a beautiful (supposedly) JavaFX GUI into a web page?  Launch it free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for a better user experience as well as a way to completely side-step the problems raised by 'browser tabs'.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The main raison why we want to embed our actually beautiful GUI is to deal with Facebook Apps integration. To be more specific, my question has two points : first focus on the browser's window and put it to front, then select our app's tab. After many searches, no solution for tab, and for the window, only native options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's absolutely no way to do this using no custom native bridge doing the job, even with a javascript bridge.
With the next versions of JavaFX neither.

And applets are not supported anymore in Chrome, so I think nobody would try that anymore.